# finding a user with maximum degree centrality score within a larger network of users in wiki articles

Tags: r

Hi I am having a problem where i want to make a network of user based on articles in a data frame named "wiki" like 
 Faid  users1   users2      ( Faid= articles), users1= network node,users2= network node)
  1      a1       u1
  1      a1       a2
  .      a1       b2
  .      u1       a2
  .      u1       b2
  1      a2       b2

2      a1       c1
  .      a1       a2
  .      a1       c2
  .      c1       a2
  .      c1       c2
  2      a2       c2

3     c2        c1
  .     c2        u2
  .     c2        u1
  .     c1        u2
  .     c1        u1
  3     u2        u1

this is just a an example I have more than  3000 article's user networks .
 what I want is to find the degree centrality scor for each user in a whole network( in all article) and shows the score in a column where (Faid 1 )have a centrality score of a user with highest degree centrality score and (Faid 2) have the highest degree centrality score .
 but the score should be of a user that belong to the network of that article. e.g
users      centrality_score
a1              100
a2              80
b1              70
b2              55
c1              10
c2              50
u1              140
u2              15
and the final dataframe would look like this 
Faid         centrality score
1              140    (# i.e. u1 has 140)
2              100
3              140
this is just an example of the data I have and the results I want. any help would highly be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the igraph-package to generate a graph:

http://igraph.org/r/ and the function centralization.degree. Use get.data.frame  to generate a graph from a data frame.

All the best Hermann

Comment: I do have the centrality score using the igraph package but I am not able to find the user with highest centrality score within the single article i.e.( for Faid =1 which user do have the highest centrality score) etc

Comment: Maybe I dont understand your problem. But ... Each vertex should have a centrality score. Did you try something like V(g)$[which.max(centrality.values)]?